# reading cookie value in play framewrok 2.2 scala template

Tags: html, scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to read a cookie value inside the play framework template (not inside a controller).  I am trying the following which is not working:

```
@ val cookieVal = request.cookies.get('PLAY_SESSION').value
```

Any suggestions to fix this will be greatly appreciated.  The reason why I am trying this is to change how the page gets rendered based on a cookie value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In templates you define `val`s as follows:

```
@defining(request.cookies.get('PLAY_SESSION').value) { theValue =>
  <div>Hello @theValue</div>
}
```

I personally prefer to read the cookies in the controller and pass them to the template if needed.

Comment: will try soon and revert - possibly on both counts (passing value to template as opposed to reading cookie in template) - thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity: `request` is not defined by default in the template, right? If it is, do you have a link to the corresponding source code ready?

Answer (score 1):

suppose PLAY_SESSION stored `"37f0983881ba00636868b42234a360d466fb944c-block_status=0&userId=159313257462171"`
and you have to render on the basis of the value of `block_status`.
then in this case you can get its value by

```
session.get("block_status").get
```

to use it in template you have to import`@implicit session:play.api.mvc.Session` at your template.
now you can easily get values at template by `@session.get("block_status").get`

Answer (score 1):

```
request.cookies.get("Org").get.value
```

Comment: Please consider adding a short explanation so to help users to understand your answer. Thanks!